# Encrypt on iPhone Decrypt in ASP.NET APP

Tags: asp.net, iphone

How can I Encrypt on iPhone Decrypt the same data in an ASP.NET application?

Should I not worry about it and just send all data by SSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the data is. If it's highly sensitive, you're probably better off using SSL. But for general information, Encryption and Decryption shouldn't matter as long as use the same encryption/decryption method (and keys) on both ends.